# Set release version automatically without prompting users - sbt-release

Tags: playframework, build, sbt, sbt-release

How can I prevent sbt-release from prompting user for Release version and Next version?

Comment: https://github.com/sbt/sbt-release - Follow the tutorial..

Comment: you can use `sbt "release release-version 2.0 next-version 2.1-SNAPSHOT with-defaults"` with `""` after `sbt`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[use the `with-defaults` option](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-release#non-interactive-release):

```
$ sbt "release with-defaults"
```

Comment: I tried this option but it is still prompting for version.

Comment: Thanks ed! I tried this option too but its not working. I get this error: "No versions are set! Was this release part executed before inquireVersions?"

Comment: sounds like you haven't defined a version for your project. Have you included a `version.sbt` file with `version in ThisBuild := "1.0.0-SNAPSHOT"`? I'd recommend following the docs closely when getting started.

Comment: I included this file and have followed the the instruction in the tutorial.I am using activator: activator "release with-defaults"instead of sbt "release with-defaults". Can this be the issue?

Comment: perhaps - at this point you'd have to share your project code to allow any further answers

Comment: Hi @ed. The issue has been resolved. I was using the latest version of the plugin  (1.0.2) and it has some issue with the with-defaults option. https://github.com/sbt/sbt-release/issues/142. I reverted back to old version. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: good to hear @saniyasaifee - would it be fair to say that my answer is correct? and if so could you mark it as such?