# How to maintain version number for builds using sbt?

Tags: scala, sbt

How can I generate my project builds with an incremental version number on each sbt package?

eg: module_2.11-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar for next build will be renamed module_2.11-0.1.1-SNAPSHOT.jar and so on...

Comment: With a quick search you can find [sbt-release](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-release)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set release version automatically without prompting users - sbt-release](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35559502/set-release-version-automatically-without-prompting-users-sbt-release)